# AWS Amplify multiple apps on seperate subdomains

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-amplify

I want two apps on one domain in different subdomains on AWS amplify. I want the main app `www.domain.com` and an admin app `admin.domain.com`. I tried creating two different amplify apps and adding the domain to both apps but can only add it to one amplify app. Is there a way to achieve this? TIA

Comment: Do you still need help? I think the way to archive this is to put the apps into one git repository and use feature branches to deploy to subdomains (like in your case to admin and www)